# Flipping bit in c

Tags: c

In this code I'm supposed to be asking the user to flip a 1 of 32 bits. When I flip the 32nd bit(index 31) I receive -2147483648 even when i used an unsigned int. How fix the flip to come out correctly?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int32_t num = 0;
   int bitC = 0;
   int number;
   char cont;
   do {
      printf("Enter a number between 1 and 1000\n");
      do {
         scanf("   %d", &num);
         if(num < 0 || num > 1000) {
            printf("Error: Number MUST be between 1 and 1000.\n");
            //printf("Please re-enter number.\n");
         }
      } while(num < 0 || num > 1000);
      printf("Choose a bit, between 0 and 31, to flip\n");
      do {
         scanf("   %d", &bitC);
         if(bitC < 0 || bitC > 31) {
            printf("Error: bit MUST be between 0 and 31\n");
            //printf("Please re-enter bit to change.\n");
         }
      } while(bitC <0 || bitC > 31);
      printf("Number before bit flip was %d\n", num);
      //num ^= (-bitC ^ num)&(1 << bitC);
      num ^= (1UL << bitC);
      printf("New number is: %d\n", num);
      printf("Would you like to shift another bit?\n");
      printf("Enter y to continue or n to quit\n");
      scanf("   %s", &cont);
   } while(cont == 'y');
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you know the number is -2147483648? Because you print it out with the wrong specifier. Use %u, or better yet %x.

Comment: Note: use unsigned types when dealing with bitmaps in integers. And the code invokes undefined behaviour if `unsigned int` has less than 32 bits or if it has 32 bits and you want to flip bit 31. Also `%d` will infoke undefined behaviour, if `int32_t` is not `typedef int int32_t;`. Use the macros in `inttypes.h`.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: If you refer to printing `num`: these two conversion type specifiers would always invoke undefined behaviour; `num` is a signed integer.

Comment: By the way you have a similar mismatch between the format string and parameter type in your call to `scanf`. You are using `%s` (string) but passing in the address of a single char. `scanf` will write whatever string the user enters into memory starting at the address of `cont` and will add a terminating `\0`. Even if the user only enters a single character, the terminating `\0` will still overwrite something else on the stack. Entering a long string will crash your program. Use `%c` to read a single char.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: these two statements: `char cont;` and  `scanf("   %s", &cont);`  add up to undefined behavior!  when using the `%s` input/conversion specifier, the `scanf()` function will always append a NUL byte (0x00) to the input, so will  (almost) always overrun the input buffer.  two things need to be done to correct this. 1) declare: `char cont[2]` and `scanf( " %1s", cont )`.  And even better fix would be: `char cont;` and `scanf(" %c", &cont );   in all cases, the returned value from this call to `scanf()` must be 1, otherwise an error occurred.

Comment: when asking a question about a runtime problem, always posted code that cleanly compiles.  Amongst other reasons the posted code does not cleanly compile is it is missing the needed `#include` statements.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )  there are several unused variables and the parameters to `main()` are unused.  Suggest the signature for `main()` be: `int main( void )`

Comment: when calling `scanf()` with the '%d' input/conversion specifier, the '%d'  specifier will consume any leading white space, so this statement: `scanf( "    %d", &num);` should really be similar to: `if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &num) ) { perror( "scanf failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`   which properly checks the returned value and allows the '%d' input/conversion specifier to do its' job of consuming any leading 'white space' and outputs an error message to `stderr` (including the reason the OS thinks the error occurred)

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code: indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is visible even with variable width fonts.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default ) via a single blank line.

Comment: this statement: `printf("Error: Number MUST be between 1 and 1000.\n");` does not match this statement: `if(num < 0 || num > 1000)`  Suggest: fprintf( stderr,  "Error; Number MUST be in the range 1...1000\n" );`  and `if( 0 >= num || 1000 < num )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using signed ints in the program right now. But the real problem is that when you printf, you're using %d, which causes printf to evaluate the argument (remember that printf has no idea what it is really, it's just a value on the stack) as a signed int even if the value passed to printf was unsigned. Use %u.

Comment: 1) `num` is signed. 2) all are inappropriate.

Comment: Oh, and there is no stack in the C language. How arguments are passed depends on the implementation.

Comment: Olaf, I don't understand what points you're making here. I know that `num` is signed--I said so: "You're using signed ints in the program right now." And while it's true that compilers may pass parameters through registers, it's not untrue to say that the parameters are "on the stack," just as it's not untrue to say that a file is "on disk" even if it in fact on a network or memory filesystem.

Comment: You mix language and implementation. The question is about the language, not an implementation. There are implementations which do not use a stack at all for typical programs. Said that: it is plain pointless to bring in this level. And using `%u` for a signed integer invokes undefined behaviour. Worse: `%d` is wrong, too, unless `int32_t` is `int` (which is not guaranteed). There are correct ways to print the fixed-width types, you don't show them.

Comment: You seem to be focused on C language arcana rather than solving this person's problem. Yes, it's true that the size of ints vary in C depending on the architecture. But he's almost certainly running on a machine with 32-bit ints, and simply changing %d to %u makes his program run correctly. That is fundamentally why his program doesn't print the expected value even when he changes num to be unsigned.

Comment: It is not me concentrating on "arcane things. I just stated it is nonsense to bring in implementation specifics here. Once more: `%u` expects an `unsigned int` parameter. `int32_t` **can** be `int`. But it also could be `long`. But never `unsigned int`. Thus it invokes undefined behaviour. `%d` **would be** correct if `int32_t` was type `int`, but there is no guarantee it is, so it also is prone to invoking UB. There are macros with the correct specifiers for the target; Use them (and use an unsigned integer)! That way you don't need to be "**almost (who is being arcane?) certain".

Comment: Oh, and: most platforms C targets are not 32 bit. I agree the one OP uses likely is, but why bother if there is a fully portable way?

Comment: Olaf, have you never written a program that depends on "undefined behavior?"

Comment: Not intentionally. I prefer to write programs which work as expected. And my customers would "kill me" (symbolically) if I did. But maybe you have written more C or C++ code in the last 25 years than I have. I still don't get why you not just correct your answer; there is just no need to rely on implementation details, less UB. It would have taken much less time. Just in case: here is the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) (well, the final draft, but that is identical except for two macros not relevant here)

Comment: The poster is obviously a C novice and is not trying to write a portable program. He just doesn't realize that printf uses the format string to determine the type of each parameter and has no information about the actual types. You seem more interested in making everyone else wrong than in actually solving the problem at hand.

Comment: The more important it is he learns writing correct C from the start. You don't help him, but teach bad coding style from the start. You don't provide a viable solution either (and if I had known that you start a nonsense discussion I might indeed have provide an answer on my own. But I assume that would just get another downvote for no reason.) I find it quite irritating you insist on pushing wrong code by a  discussion like "well, it might work", although a correct solution is at hand and does not even require more effort.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137889/discussion-between-willis-blackburn-and-olaf).

Answer (score 0):

here is a version of the posted code that cleanly compiles and doesn't have the logic and data flaws inherent in the OPs posted code.

It also properly outputs error messages to `stderr` rather than `stdout` and with those error messages includes the reason the OS thinks the error occurred.

```
#include <stdio.h>    // scanf(), printf(), fprintf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <inttypes.h> // uint32_t


int main( void )
{

   uint32_t num  = 0;
   uint32_t bitC = 0;
   char cont     = 'y';

   do
   {
      printf("Enter a number in the range 1...1000\n");

      do
      {
         if( 1 != scanf("%u", &num) )
         {
             perror( "scanf for number failed" );
             exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
         }

         // implied else, scanf successful

         // the 'num' is to check != 0
         if( !num || 1000 < num )
         {
            printf("Error: Number MUST be in range 1...1000.\n");
         }

         else
         {
             break;
         }

      } while(1);

      printf("Choose a bit, in range 0...31, to flip\n");

      do
      {
         if( 1 != scanf("%u", &bitC) )
         {
             perror( "scanf for bit number failed" );
             exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
         }

         // implied else, scanf successful

         if( bitC > 31 )
         {
            fprintf( stderr, "Error: bit must be in range 0...31\n" );
         }

         else
         {
             break;
         }

      } while(1);

      printf("Number before bit flip was %u\n", num);

      num ^= (1U << bitC);

      printf("New number is: %u\n", num);

      printf("Would you like to shift another bit?\n");
      printf("Enter y to continue or n to quit\n");

      if( 1 != scanf(" %c", &cont) )
      {
          perror( "scanf for continuing failed" );
          exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
      }

   } while('y' == cont || 'Y' == cont );
   return 0;
}
```